# Is there a protractor.promise.when() method?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I see that I can use `protractor.promise.all()`. Is there a `protractor.promise.when()`? And where can I find out more about it and how to use it?

My problem is I need to resolve all `getText()` promises, determine which ones fail and provide blanks for those that failed.

For example:

```
function getValues() {
    let pFirstName = $('#firstname').getText();
    let pLastName = $('#lastname').getText();
    let pSSN = $('#ssn').getText();
    return protractor.promise.when([pFirstName, pLastName, pSSN])
        .then(function(values) {
            return {
                "first": values[0],
                "last": values[1],
                "ssn": values[2]    // This value may or may not be on the DOM, how do I check it and provide an alternate value?
            };
        });
}
```

**UPDATE:**
As I'm continuing my research, I see this is more of a webdriver issue. And, perhaps I need to pull in Bluebird. I'm not sure.

To answer the question below, "what do you mean by which ones fail?"
Suppose that the `$('#ssn')` ElementFinder doesn't actually find an element that matches `#ssn`. The `getText()` method would reject on the promise and deliver an element not found error.  And, so, I would the following two situations:

```
<span id="firstname">Joe</span>
<span id="lastname">Smith</span>
<span id="ssn">123-45-6789</span>
```

---

```
getValues().then(res => console.log(res));
```

would return `{"first": "Joe","last":"Smith","ssn":"123-45-6789"}`

In the following situation, where a user is not supposed to see the SSN, and angular doesn't even create the element, we may have:

```
<span id="firstname">Joe</span>
<span id="lastname">Smith</span>
```

---

```
getValues().then(res => console.log());
```

I would expect that the return should be: `{"first":"Joe","last":"Smith"}` or `{"first":"Joe","last":"Smith","ssn":""}`

Comment: what do you mean by `which ones fail`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an another idea  - a more *generic* one - get all the related `span` elements and use [`reduce()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce) to return an object with input ids and texts:

```
var inputs = $$("span[id]");  // TODO: make the locator more specific
var values = inputs.reduce(function (obj, input) {
    return input.getAttribute("id").then(function (fieldName) {
        return input.getText().then(function (fieldValue) {
            obj[fieldName] = fieldValue;
        });
    });
}, {});
```

You can also change `{}` to, say, `{"firstname": "", "lastname": "", "ssn": ""}` to have the default values for fields that don't exist.

Comment: I do like this approach. I'll have to see how the id's align with my desired property names on the result for the app I'm testing against. This solution includes only what is there and not anything else. Whereas my solution above gives blank values to properties that don't exist.

Comment: @Machtyn thanks, as far as the default values - updated with one way to approach it. Or, you can post-process the `values` and fill out the missing fields.

Answer (score 1):

Unless a better answer comes along, I think this may be the answer (just catch the reject during the getText() call).

```
function getValues() {
let pFirstName = $('#firstname').getText().catch(() => "");
let pLastName = $('#lastname').getText().catch(() => "");
let pSSN = $('#ssn').getText().catch(() => "");

return protractor.promise.when([pFirstName, pLastName, pSSN])
    .then(function(values) {
        return {
            "first": values[0],
            "last": values[1],
            "ssn": values[2]
        };
    });
}
```

At least, it works when I do something similar in JSFiddle:

```js
function iffy(rVal, cond)  {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        if (cond) {
            resolve(rVal);
        } else {
         reject(new Error("This is in error"));
        }
    });
}

let pTruthy = iffy("true", true)
    .catch(() => "Caught the error");
let pFalsy = iffy("false", false)
    .catch(() => "Caught the error");

Promise.all([pTruthy, pFalsy])
    .then(values => console.log(values))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

iffy("false", false)
    .then(val => console.log(val))
    .catch(err => console.log(err.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the very generic approach, but you can check if the SSN field is present explicitly. Something along these lines:

```
function getValues() {
    let pFirstName = $('#firstname').getText();
    let pLastName = $('#lastname').getText();
    let isSSNPresent = $('#ssn').isPresent();
    return protractor.promise.all([pFirstName, pLastName, isSSNPresent]).then(function(values) {
        let result = {
            "first": values[0],
            "last": values[1]
        };

        if (values[2]) {
            $('#ssn').getText().then(function (ssn) {
                result.ssn = ssn
            });
        } 
        return result;
    });
}
```

(not tested)

Comment: The problem I see with this is that it looks like it will return the result before resolving the getText() within the if statement.  Is that true or am I misunderstanding the flow?

Comment: @Machtyn that's what I am also afraid of..I will test it. Thanks, good point!

Comment: @Machtyn just checked locally and it works for me! The additional field set by the inner `getText()` call is getting set as well. Does it work for you?